# how to use windows authentication on shared hosting?

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I have developed a web application in ASP.Net 3.5 with authentication set as "Windows Authentication" and is working fine my local network.
 Now my client asked me to deploy it on shared server.  I have a shared windows hosting for asp.net website deployment. how can I enable windows authentication at server, like creating user and password on Active Directory, creating groups etc.  as we can do all this thing at our local Windows server 2003/ 2008.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is a shared server that you have no control over, you will not be able to implement this type of security; you would have to change your security model to use a database so you could store the credentials there.  It is possible to take an AD store and dump it into a database, so that could be an option (as long as it's being updated frequently).

Comment: Dear Brian,  Thanks for your prompt reply. My clients do not want to use database based login credentials. It should be exactly Windows Based authentication, they do not want to implement login box or register user etc. It should be windows user login popop if needed, i.e. automatically login with windows credentials. I am getting confused, where should i can create user and other stuff. This application is working fine at my local as i am able to do any thing at my windows server 2003/2008. User auotmatically gets login as per their credentials.

Comment: I am also going to use SSRS in the same application within few days with this application.

Also if its not possible on shared hosting, would it be possible if i go for windows reseller hosting plan or dedicated hosting plan. I tried to find this information on some hosting sites but didn't get proper information.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a database, the only other option is for your clients to purchase a VPS or cloud server plan (think amazon, azure, etc). This would allow you a server to work with where you can configure users through windows authentication. You can get pretty good VPS plans through a variety of hosts for under 100 dollars a month. I personally user GoDaddy at around 50 a month.

if you're on shared hosting there is no way to use windows authentication as you don't have direct access to the server operating system.